# Autodesk Forge Viewer gives empty model (no geometry) issue on IFC file that works in BIM360

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-bim360

An IFC file which can be displayed in BIM 360 shows empty model problem in our platforms and official Online Forge Viewer. I have tried to download it from BIM360 and upload it to Forge, it didn't work again. Except Forge, in three different platforms(BIM 360 included) the IFC file can be viewed.

It is not the first time that we upload an IFC file, is there a point that I miss on export settings or versions of IFC ?

Comment: There should be no special settings needed when processing IFC files. Consider sharing the IFC model with us via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`, and we will take a look.

Comment: @PetrBroz Hi, I've sent the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to submit the translation job with `switchLoader: true` or `conversionMethod: modern` to use the modern IFC translation pipeline (Revit based). It's turned on by default for the BIM360 Docs. See documentation here for the SVF output options: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/#body-structure

BTW, according to our autodesk viewer team, viewer.autodesk.com is using the old one (legacy), so this is the main difference.