# No model issue for IFC Models in the Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, ifc

Need help on the similar topic posted below:
[Autodesk Forge Viewer gives empty model (no geometry) issue on IFC file that works in BIM360](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64753793/autodesk-forge-viewer-gives-empty-model-no-geometry-issue-on-ifc-file-that-wor)

As suggested in the article, I have added the required options for the translation, and the model creates the correct derivatives. But , still the Viewer shows the same error of "model is empty. there is no geometry for the viewer to show" Please suggest, if the Viewer also needs to be handled differently to load these "modern" conversion-based files. Thanks very much.

Comment: Could you consider sharing a non-confidential reproducible IFC model demonstrating this issue to forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com? I will help you pass to our engineering team for investigations.

Comment: @EasonKang - Thanks Eason for your response. I have shared the files with you.

Comment: thank you. I saw your support case in the Forge Help system. Let me investigate the model first. Will get back to you A.S.A.P.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reproducible model. The translation result looks fine while using the modern conversion method. I replied to you via Forge Help. It contains a snapshot of my test.

So, could you have a try? This is the code example of how I send the translation request using the modern conversion method.

**Note.** if you want to override an existing translation result, please be sure to set the header parameter `x-ads-force: true`.

```sh
curl --location --request POST 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'x-ads-force: true' \
--data '{
  "input": {
    "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bXlidWNrZXQvSUZDX0JydWVja2VfS2xpbmdlbmJlcmdfNC56aXA"
  },
  "output": {
    "formats": [
      {
        "type": "svf",
        "views": [
          "3d"
        ],
        "advanced": {
          "conversionMethod": "modern"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}'
```

ref: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/#headers